# Is it better to animate translate for one large area or lots of small areas?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm working on a project with lots and lots of animation. I've been sticking to the properties that perform the best - translate, opacity, scale, etc. But I'm still having problems with performance on mobile. I do have to insert some new dom elements here and there, but I try to do that between animations. One thing that I think might be slowing it down is the fact that I have a large div being translated with lots of other elements inside of it. (think carousel). I'm beginning to think perhaps performance could be improved by simultaneously animating the individual elements, however I can't find any proof of this while searching.

Does anyone know if one way is better? Having some documentation to back up the claim would be great! I'd just refactor the project and find out for myself, but I'm against a deadline, and I don't want to rip the entire project apart for a hunch.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you measuring the performance on mobile?

Comment: I'm not measuring mobile specifically. Using Chrome's dev tools to view the layouts/paints. Just seeing some jankiness when viewing on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to translate the parent instead of all children.
The problem is that you want to animate a lot of element.

Have you try to use hardware acceleration?
Thi isn't the right way, but at the moment is the only one that do the stuff.

```
.anim {
   ...
   transform: translateZ(0);
   ...
}
```